# mongorestore --oplogReplay never compleates

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

We are useing mongoDB and backing up our databases each day, and saving the recorded oplogs each hour for incronmental backups.

Restoring the backups and oplogs work as expected, we are restoreing the initial backup with:

```
mongorestore --drop --oplogReplay -path "path to backup dump"
```

and then applying each of the oplogs in order with:

```
mongorestore --stopOnError --oplogReplay "path to oplog dump"
```

However, there always seems to be one oplog in our collection of oplogs which never compleates, for example:

```
2015-12-14T15:57:31.931+1100    building a list of dbs and collections to restore from C:\oplogs\oplog-0102\local dir
2015-12-14T15:57:31.932+1100    replaying oplog
2015-12-14T15:57:34.943+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:37.942+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:40.941+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:43.941+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:46.942+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:49.942+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:52.941+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:55.942+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
2015-12-14T15:57:58.941+1100    [########################] oplog    280.7 KB/280.7 KB (100.0%)
```

This replaying oplog goes on forever and never finishes. If i force close mongorestore in task manager and reset the mongo service, the restore for that oplog appears to have completed successfully.

Is there an alternative method i can try to restore or something i'm doing wrong here? I hope this is enough information.

**Edit:**
I'm pleased mongo is open source, I looked through the source code of mongorestore, and implemented my own version in c#. mongorestore runs an "applyOps" command on the entries provided in the oplog.bson file.
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/applyOps/

after doing a similar thing in c#, i found that the command never finishes when one of those entries is trying the update the "system.indexes" collection with:

**Note:** i've removed the actual db/collection name etc.

```
{ 
    "ts" : Timestamp(1450063020, 1), 
    "h" : NumberLong("513294342778035173"), 
    "v" : 2, 
    "op" : "i", 
    "ns" : "myDb.system.indexes", 
    "o" : { 
        "ns" : "myDb.randomCollection", 
        "key" : { 
            "SomeKeyValue" : 1 
        }, 
        "name" : "SomeKeyValue", 
        "background" : true, 
        "sparse" : true, 
        "unique" : true 
    } 
}
```

For the moment, i have filtered out all entries which are modifying a "system.indexes" collection, which feels like a really bad idea.

Comment: you are running restore as a user who has certain permissions - is creating new indexes one of those permissions?

Comment: it's not unsafe to filter out the index related entries - you can do it with "--noIndexRestore" option in mongorestore more elegantly though.